# How to set 'auto' for upper limit, but keep a fixed lower limit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to set the upper limit of the y-axis to 'auto', but I want to keep the lower limit of the y-axis to always be zero.  I tried 'auto' and 'autorange', but those don't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(results_plt,title,filename):

    ############################
    # Plot results

    # mirror result table such that each parameter forms an own data array
    plt.cla()
    #print results_plt
    XY_results = []

    XY_results = zip( *results_plt)

    plt.plot(XY_results[0], XY_results[2], marker = ".")

    plt.title('%s' % (title) )
    plt.xlabel('Input Voltage [V]')
    plt.ylabel('Input Current [mA]')

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlim(3.0, 4.2)  #***I want to keep these values fixed"
    plt.ylim([0, 80]) #****CHANGE**** I want to change '80' to auto, but still keep 0 as the lower limit 
    plt.savefig(path+filename+'.png')
```

Answer (score 157):

You can pass just `left` or `right` to `set_xlim`:

```
plt.gca().set_xlim(left=0)
```

For the y axis, use `bottom` or `top`:

```
plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

Important note: "you must use the functions AFTER you have plotted the data. If you don't do this, it will use the default 0 for left/bottom and 1 for top/right." - [Luc's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805331/229792)

Comment: I got an error when I passed the left for the set_ylim.  

I used this instead: plt.gca().set_ylim(ymin=0)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also use `plt.xlim` or `plt.ylim` to set the limits for the current axis.

Comment: When I do this the upper limit sticks to whatever value the window instantiates in. It does not remain auto-scaling.

Comment: Same issue as @Elliot here. Can be fixed by setting the (one-sided) ylim/xlim after ploting the values.

Comment: @vietnastee `set_ylim` takes parameters `bottom` and `top` instead.

Comment: Make sure to set the limit after plotting data, or the upper limit will default to 1.

Answer (score 59):

Just set `xlim` for one of the limits:

```
plt.xlim(left=0)
```

Comment: `xmin` and `xmax` have been deprecated in favour of `left` and `right` in Matplotlib 3.0.

Answer (score 18):

As aforementioned and according to the matplotlib documentation, the x-limits of a given axis `ax` can be set using the [`set_xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) method of the `matplotlib.axes.Axes` class.

For instance,

```
>>> ax.set_xlim(left_limit, right_limit)
>>> ax.set_xlim((left_limit, right_limit))
>>> ax.set_xlim(left=left_limit, right=right_limit)
```

One limit may be left unchanged (e.g. the left limit):

```
>>> ax.set_xlim((None, right_limit))
>>> ax.set_xlim(None, right_limit)
>>> ax.set_xlim(left=None, right=right_limit)
>>> ax.set_xlim(right=right_limit)
```

To set the x-limits of the current axis, the `matplotlib.pyplot` module contains the `xlim` function that just wraps  `matplotlib.pyplot.gca` and `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim`.

```
def xlim(*args, **kwargs):
    ax = gca()
    if not args and not kwargs:
        return ax.get_xlim()
    ret = ax.set_xlim(*args, **kwargs)
    return ret
```

Similarly, for the y-limits, use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim` or `matplotlib.pyplot.ylim`. The keyword arguments are `top` and `bottom`.

Answer (score 12):

The `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` permit `None` values to achieve this. However, you must use the functions **AFTER** you have plotted the data. If you don't do this, it will use the default 0 for left/bottom and 1 for top/right. It does not recalculate the "automatic" limit each time you plot new data once you have set the limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([0, 1, 4, 5], [3, 5, 6, 9])
ax.set_xlim(left=2, right=None)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=None, top=7)

plt.show()
```

(I.e., in the above example, if you would do `ax.plot(...)` at the end, it won't give the desired effect.)

Comment: This answer is precious. Just using "none" does not change anything, it's important to first plot the data, then set the limit and finally show the chart.

Answer (score 6):

Just add a point on @silvio 's: if you use axis to plot like `figure, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,2,1)`. Then `ax1.set_xlim(xmin = 0)` also works!

Comment: This will be depreciated in matplotlib v3.0 according to a warning I got

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
ax.set_xlim((None,upper_limit))
ax.set_xlim((lower_limit,None))
```

That is helpful if you want to use set(), which allows you to set several parameters at once:

```
ax.set(xlim=(None, 3e9), title='my_title', xlabel='my_x_label', ylabel='my_ylabel')
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to summarize all possible variants in a single answer, since the most commonly used case with `plt.xlim([0, None])` was not convered until now. But since this provides the handiest/shortest form, I really think it deserves being mentioned :D

### When using `matplotlib.pyplot` aka. "`plt`"

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...

# left limit is 0, right is "auto"
# this is all equivalent
plt.xlim(left=0)
plt.xlim(left=0, right=None)
plt.xlim([0, None]) # this is the shortest solution

# upper limit is 10, lower is "auto"
# this is all equivalent
plt.ylim(top=10)
plt.ylim(bottom=None, top=10)
plt.ylim([None, 10])
```

### When using an axis object aka. "`ax`"

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example subplot (this creates 2 axes in "ax")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

# left limit is 0, right is "auto"
# this is all equivalent
ax[0].set_xlim(left=0)
ax[0].set_xlim(left=0, right=None)
ax[0].set_xlim([0, None]) # this is the shortest solution

# upper limit is 10, lower is "auto"
# this is all equivalent
ax[0].set_ylim(top=10)
ax[0].set_ylim(bottom=None, top=10)
ax[0].set_ylim([None, 10])
```