# Fix only one axis limit, set other to auto

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The following `MWE` produces a simple scatter plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some random two-dimensional data:
m1 = np.random.normal(size=100)
m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=100)

# Plot data with 1.0 max limit in y.
plt.figure()
# Set x axis limit.
plt.xlim(0., 1.0)
# Plot points.
plt.scatter(m1, m2)
# Show.
plt.show()
```

In this plot the x axis limits are set to `[0., 1.]`. I need to set the *upper* y axis limit to 1. leaving the lower limit to whatever the min value in `m2` is (ie: let `python` decide the lower limit).

In this particular case I could just use `plt.ylim(min(m2), 1.0)` but my actual code is far more complicated with lots of things being plotted so doing this is not really an option.

I've tried setting:

```
plt.ylim(top=1.)
```

and also:

```
plt.gca().set_ylim(top=1.)
```

as advised here [How to set 'auto' for upper limit, but keep a fixed lower limit with matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744990/how-to-set-auto-for-upper-limit-but-keep-a-fixed-lower-limit-with-matplotlib?rq=1), but neither command seems to work. They both correctly set the upper limit in the y axis to 1. but they also force a lower limit of 0. which I don't want.

I'm using `Python 2.7.3` and `Matplotlib 1.2.1`.

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?  These both work as expected for me

Comment: I suspect this is a bug, and if possible you should upgrade to 1.3 (but I can't find the issue where it got fixed). Failing that the workaround from @bhajunsingh should work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the concern is simply that a lot of data is being plotted, why not retrieve the plot's lower y-limit and use that when setting the limits?

```
plt.ylim(plt.ylim()[0], 1.0)
```

Or analogously for a particular axis. A bit ugly, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

---

The issue actually resides in the fact that setting the limits before plotting disables autoscaling.  The limits for both the x and y axes are, by default, `(0.0, 1.0)`, which is why the lower y limit remains at 0.

The solution is simply to set the plot limits after calling all plot commands.  Or you can [re-enable autoscaling](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale) if needed

Comment: I would suggest using the OO interface: `ax = plt.gca(); cur_ylim = ax.get_ylim(); ax.set_ylim([cur_ylim[0], 1])`

Comment: Bhajun unfortunately your answer also fails as does tcaswell's variation (which is really strange)

Comment: @Gabriel I find that strange since it appears to work correctly for me, and tcaswell also noted that your code worked as expected.  Perhaps testing with a different version of matplotlib is worth a try.

Comment: It appears that I'll need to update Matplotlib. Just to be sure, which version are you running?

Comment: @Gabriel, I have an older version, `1.1.1rc` on Python 2.7.3, on the machine I tested with.

Comment: Well that makes it even weirder. Just so you'll believe me, I've added to the original question a screenshot of my code with your workaround showing the limits.

Comment: Try setting the limits **after** plotting your data - so after calling `plt.scatter`.

Comment: I should've thought of that. It works now Bhajun, could you please make this clear in your answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, I should have realized it earlier as well.  But it was a learning exercise for all of us.  I updated my answer.